# R: Error in simple call to sum() that I cannot reproduce - how can I find what the problem object is?

Tags: r, debugging, sum

I am running these two simple lines of code:

```
vector <- c(2.5, 2.5, NA)
sum(vector, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in sum(vector, na.rm = TRUE) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

But if I run a `reprex`, then `sum()` works:

```r
vector <- c(2.5, 2.5, NA)
sum(vector, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 5
```

If I restart `R` I get the same error.

If I remove all objects, the function works.

How can I find which object is giving me this problem? Do I have to go through the file line by line and check the call to `sum()` every time I introduce a new object? I hope there is a better way.

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: In your environment are you overwriting/creating a new function with the same name `sum`?

Comment: Of course, that's what I did. Thank you @LMc

Comment: Is there a way of being warned when overwriting a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LMc noticed, I had created another function called `sum()`:

```r
sum <- function(a,b){a+b}
vector <- c(2.5, 2.5, NA)
sum(vector, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Error in sum(vector, na.rm = TRUE): unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: just do  `rm(sum)` and your problem should be solved